# Add file to FormData via Javascript but NOT posting via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, post, dropzone.js

I'm using the [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). The drag'n'drop part is working.
Now I have to upload it. But I don't want to upload it via AJAX.

I have a form with fields like `name`, `location`, etc. I want to add the files in to the form and go with the default behavior from the browser when I click on the submit button.

I managed to add the Files to the JavaScript object FormData, but when I submit and check the Data there are no files.

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("upload", file.upload);
});
```

Comment: for small files maby read as base64 and send as <input type="hidden" />

Comment: Did you add this to the form? **enctype='multipart/form-data'**

Comment: @Niklas yes it's there

Comment: @RolandStarke there gonna be big files